# Controller Configuration in AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to configure one (and only one) of my Controller to accept only `application/xml` requests.

In the past i used IControllerConfiguration to do that like described [here (Per-Controller configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793213/479659).

How can i do that in Aspnet Core ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Consumes`-Annotation together with the accepted content type on Controller or Action level.

With

```
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] CallModel model)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

calls to this controller will only succeed if the client provides Content-Type header of `application/xml`. Otherwise a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may simply check Request AcceptTypes / Content-Type headers (like `if request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/xml")`) and stop request processing.
2. Accordingly to link you provided, seems like  you just want to ignore content type and always return an XML result. In this case you may use a new [Produces](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/ProducesAttribute/) attribute.

> A filter that specifies the expected System.Type the action will return and the supported response content types. The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesAttribute.ContentTypes value is used to set Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ContentTypes.

Apply attribute to your controller

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public YourXmlController : Controller { }
```

or only to specific controller action:

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public Object ControllerAction()
{
    return new { text = "hello world" };
}
```

Note, that [XML formatter](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/11/formatters-asp-net-mvc-6/) does not enabled by default, so you should add one using MvcOptions:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    //options.InputFormatters.Add( ... );
    //options.OutputFormatters.Add( ... );
});
```

Comment: There is an extension method to do this. `services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/DependencyInjection/MvcXmlMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L38